# how to select a textbox on sheet 1?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi how do I select textbox1 on sheet 1

```
textbox1.select
```

Comment: Is it a form type or an ActiveX type? But, you place questions, people ask for clarifications, you do not clarify anything and ask something else... Is this a normal way of acting here?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand what clarification I need to give, maybe I asked something wrong?

Comment: Didn't you ask a question "how to select the cell based on the address"?

Comment: from a textbox on sheet 1, I search for values ​​in a table on sheet 2, after I have verified what I was looking for, returning to sheet 1, I would like the cursor to automatically position itself inside the textbox. Do you mean this as clarification?

Comment: This is not required clarification, but necessary, **because selecting a text box means something completely different**. I was referring to your question I mentioned above. And how do you like the code to know that you returned to sheet 1?

Comment: My code used to answer your question **as it was formulated**. It selects the text box. Before you told us a different story, but in a comment... You must firstly learn how to ask questions. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't want to argue, I thought I expressed myself correctly, obviously I thought wrong, I apologize again.

Comment: Not a matter of arguing, I tried answering your questions some times, but never they were as they should be. That's why I tried helping you, at least, to learn asking a question. What about the other thread where you did not, at least, clarify anything, even if comments were asking for clarifications? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68483349/how-to-select-the-cell-based-on-the-address). Placed two hours ago...